# Poor forwarding performance between two WireGuard tunnels

Tags: networking, iptables, routing, performance, wireguard

I've got a dedicated server (Ubuntu Server 20.04), running two WireGuard interfaces:

- `wg0` is used to connect end-users, like laptops, mobile devices, etc.
- `wg1` is a tunnel to a 3rd-party VPN service

`wg1` is set as the default route on the server itself:

```
~ ip route get 8.8.8.8
8.8.8.8 dev wg1 table 51820 src 10.13.128.233 uid 0
```

Then, a NAT is set up, to masquerade traffic coming from `wg0` tunnel (end-users) onto `wg1` tunnel (3rd-party VPN service):

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wg1 -j MASQUERADE
```

The simplified scheme thus looks like this:

```
(end-users) ----> wg0 ----> (Hetzner server) ----> NAT ----> wg1 ----> (3rd-party VPN)
```

`wg0` config is super-minimal, with no MTU option specified. Laptop clients use default MTU, iperf tests below were performed on laptops.

`wg1` config specifies 1420 as MTU value.

The problem is, I'm getting a subpar internet browsing performance on end-user devices. I believe the problem lies in server configuration, and not the network, because I've performed three tests:

1. Ran command-line tests **on the server** for Fast.com using awesome [fast-cli](https://github.com/sindresorhus/fast-cli) and SpeedTest.net CLI utility. Both showed 1 Gbps performance via `wg1` tunnel from server to internet.
2. Ran `iperf` **from several end-user devices to the server** via `wg0` tunnel. Tests showed 80-90 Mbps performance from end-user to the server.
3. Finally, I ran Fast.com and SpeedTest.net tests **on end-user devices** themselves. Tests showed performance ranging from 20 to 27 Mbps when forwarding traffic from end-user via `wg0` to `wg1` tunnel and to internet.

To recap: server-to-internet WireGuard performance is fine at 1Gbps. End-user to server WireGuard performance is great too, almost at 100 Mbps. However, end-user to internet performance via two WireGuard tunnels, as shown on scheme above, drops to 20-27 Mbps.

My IPv4 stack settings are all defaults expect the usual forwarding option.

Idk if this is normal, but loss of 70-75% bandwidth seems like a lot. Would really much appreciate any advice on the matter, cause not really sure how to troubleshoot this further!